# Does C# Monitor.Wait() suffer from spurious wakeups?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading

Java's [Object.wait()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) warns against "spurious wakeups" but C#'s [Monitor.wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syehfawa.aspx) doesn't seem to mention it at all.

Seeing how Mono is implemented on top of Linux, and Linux has [spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup#Spurious_wakeup_in_Linux), shouldn't this be documented somewhere?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Joe Duffy's ["Concurrent Programming On Windows"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) mentions this (P311-312, P598). This bit is interesting:

> Note that in all of the above examples, threads must be resilient to something called spurious wake-ups - code that uses condition variables should remain correct and lively even in cases where it is awoken prematurely, that is, before the condition being sought has been established. This is not because the implementation will actually do such things (although some implementations on other platforms like Java and Pthreads are known to do so), nor because code will wake threads intentionally when it's unnecessary, but rather due to the fact that there is no guarantee around when a thread that has been awakened will become scheduled. Condition variables are not fair. It's possible - and even likely - that another thread will acquire the associated lock and make the condition false again before the awakened thread has a chance to reacquire the lock and return to the critical region.

He then gives the normal pattern for a while loop testing the condition.

I would say that from this it's reasonable to expect that `Monitor.Wait` *won't* normally wake you prematurely, and that if you absolutely *know* that nothing else can have changed the condition then you *might* be able to get away without the condition loop: but that it's safer to include it anyway, just in case your logic is inaccurate.

Comment: I'm checking with Joe directly to see if my extrapolation is correct.

Comment: Did Joe get back to you on that? On Page 207 of the same book he states that the CLR uses a common (alertable) waiting routine any time you block, including blocking calls to Monitor. Would this imply that in addition to the 'apparent' spurious wakeups you mention, your Wait could also be subject to a 'genuine' supirous wakeup caused by an Asynchronous Procedure Call?

Comment: Except... in *Java* on Windows 2000, XP and 7 I have absolutely demonstrated that spurious wakeups do occur, and the reason is probably hardware - it's unlikely (but not impossible) that C# is able to avoid this where Java cannot.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: Well I'd definitely "do the right thing" and assume it *might* happen - but I don't think I've ever seen it myself. Will edit a little.

Comment: Now that's interesting, and confusing. Two different concepts seems to be put under the same moniker "spurious wakeup". Really spurious: "awoken [...] before the condition being sought has been established". Kind of oversleep: scheduled after the condition was falsified again.
If a scheduler could equate "awoken" with "scheduled", this second issue would vanish.

Comment: [This short article by Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180201-00/?p=97946) states that spurious wakeups are a thing in Win32 conditional variables.  Based on his description of the causes, it implies to me that these conditions (stolen wakeups, overwaking) are likely a part of similar Win32 sync mechanisms.