# How to use TimeUnit.timedWait() without losing nanosecond precision?

Tags: java, concurrency, time-wait

I'm trying to implement [Future.get(long, TimeUnit)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) in terms of [TimeUnit.timedWait(Object, long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#timedWait%28java.lang.Object,%20long%29).

It's not clear how to use `TimeUnit.timedWait(Object, long)` in a way that handles spurious wakeups without losing the nanosecond component of TimeUnit. Normally you'd do something like this:

```
public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
{
  long expirationTime = new Date().getTime() + unit.toMillis(timeout);
  while (!condition)
  {
    long timeLeft = expirationTime - new Date().getTime();
    if (timeLeft <= 0)
      throw new TimeoutException();
    unit.timedWait(object, timeLeft);
  }
}
```

but you lose the nanosecond component. If everyone is simply dropping the nanosecond component then what is the point of `TimeUnit` even supporting nanoseconds and offering `TimeUnit.timedWait()`?

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions where you're concerned about spurious wakeups? Is there something in the code that makes it difficult to be clear on who's controlling the objects Monitor?

Comment: I am quite certain who is controlling the object Monitor. Spurious wakeups refer to the fact that the wait() operation may return even if no one invoked notify() or a timeout has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) seems to be the easiest way to implement this:

```
public class MutableFuture<T> implements Future<T>
{
  private final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
  private T value;
  private Throwable throwable;

  public synchronized boolean isDone()
  {
    return done.getCount() == 0;
  }

  public synchronized T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException
  {
    if (!done.await(timeout, unit))
      throw new TimeoutException();
    if (throwable != null)
      throw new ExecutionException(throwable);
    return value;
  }

  // remaining methods left as exercise to the reader :)
}
```

CountdownLatch is not vulnerable to [spurious wakeups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461956/14731) (because it can check the latch state internally before returning).

Answer (score 3):

Before you wait, store the time at which you want to timeout.

Before you notify the waiting thread, set some shared (synchronized) state signalling that the waiting thread should stop waiting because the computation is complete.

When your thread wakes up from the wait for whatever reason it should check the shared state to see if it should stop waiting, and it should also check how long is left before the timeout expires. If the timeout has not expired, and the shared state tells does not say to stop waiting then you should wait again (but using a new shorter time out calculated from the current time).

Comment: It's not clear how to store the time at which you want to timeout without losing the nanosecond component of TimeUnit. If everyone is simply dropping the nanosecond component then what is the point of TimeUnit even supporting nanoseconds and offering TimeUnit.timedWait()?

Comment: Well I can't really say why they chose to allow nanosecond precision. In practice I doubt you will get that precision anyway from an ordinary operating system. And if you do need that precision then using a garbage collected language sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more TimeUnit-centric but I've given you an up-vote for the great Object.wait() advise.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the [Object.wait(long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) spec:

A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always occur in loops, like this one:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait(timeout);
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

(For more information on this topic, see Section 3.2.3 in Doug Lea's "Concurrent Programming in Java (Second Edition)" (Addison-Wesley, 2000), or Item 50 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java Programming Language Guide" (Addison-Wesley, 2001).

Comment: You need to remember to decrease the timeout the second time you wait as some of the time has already passed.