# does .push() fail or wait while locked in this code example?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locking, websocket, queue

Wow, I wish I'd known about this page https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp written by my c++ hero https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047661/zaphoyd before I started my c++ websocket adventure.  Tons of lessons there.

If I'm reading it correctly (that's a stretch lol), it looks like connections and message sends & receipts are all handled in a single thread (can't wait til he "multi-threads" that or whatever it's called since he says in this basic example http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/server-initiated-messages that `WebSocket++ handlers block core networking functions.  While this program is running its send loop in on_message, no new connections are being processed and no new messages are being received.`) and a separate thread `boost::thread(bind(&broadcast_server::process_messages,&server));` is set up to actually process the messages while the primary websocket++ thread simply adds to the queue the necessary information.

Please clear up my lack of knowledge: will the `.push()` fail if it happens at the same time as this section of code in the link

```
while(m_actions.empty()) {
    m_action_cond.wait(lock);
}

action a = m_actions.front();
m_actions.pop();

lock.unlock();
```

or does the `.push()` simply wait for the lock to be released?

Comment: `std::queue` is not multi-threading aware. You can't lock it, and it doesn't fail or wait during contention. (Though contention involving a write will no doubt result in undefined behavior causing sporadic crashes.)

Comment: @CoryNelson the code the OP linked to is coded correctly to acquire the lock before calling `push`

Comment: Indeed. OP worded his question in a way that indicates a misunderstanding of `std::queue`'s involvement in locking.

Comment: yes, I know, but he asked about what was happening in that particular example, so it's more helpful to explain what's happening there in addition to correcting that misunderstanding...anyway, i already answered, so no worries

Comment: @CoryNelson +1 for bottom line: sporadic crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::queue<T>` doesn't know anything about threading on its own; however, in the code linked, all calls to `push` are wrapped like the following:

```
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_action_lock);
    //std::cout << "on_open" << std::endl;
    m_actions.push(action(SUBSCRIBE,hdl));
    lock.unlock();
    m_action_cond.notify_one();
```

The constructor of the `lock` object above internally calls `m_action_lock.lock()` which blocks until the lock is released.

Note that `m_action_cond.wait(lock)`, in the code you pasted in your question, unlocks the lock while waiting for the condition, and acquires the lock again after it has been woken up (either due to a signal from another thread, or [possibly spuriously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups)), so it doesn't prevent the producer (the one doing the `push`) thread from acquiring the lock while it's waiting: it's only between waking up and the call to `lock.unlock()` that blocking occurs.

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with the `push`; if you call `push` without acquiring the lock first it will execute but will have undefined effects, because of the data race: the constructor of `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>` will block, though, until the lock can be acquired.

Comment: (that comment was aimed at the comment you deleted...I'll leave it in case it's helpful)