# passing bool by reference and use its latest value

Tags: c++, boost, thread-synchronization

I have the following code:

```
MyClass::aMethod()
{
    ...
    bool isStarted = false;

    boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::CheckTimeoutThread, this, isStarted));

    ...//some time later
    isStarted = true;
    ...
}

MyClass::checkTimeoutThread(bool &isStarted)
{
    ...//some code here
    while(anotherFlag)
    {
        ...//do something
        if(isStarted)//ALWAYS THE INITIAL VALUE OF FALSE
        {
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I was expected the **isStarted** variable can be used as a flag but I am wrong or I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost::thread` will store  copy of its arguments. But you can simulate a reference by passing a `reference_wrapper` with the help of `boost::ref`. Also note that you don't need to call `boost::bind`:

```
boost::thread t(&MyClass::CheckTimeoutThread, this, boost::ref(isStarted));
```

But note that you now have a race condiiton on `isStarted`. You need to either synchrise access to it with, say, mutexes, or use an atomic type, if available on your platform (if you have C++11, then you can use `std::atomic<bool>`, as suggested by @PeteBecker.)

**Edit** Obviously all of the above assumes that `isStated` lives at least as long as the `thread` that uses it. In practice, this means the thread must be done by the time `aMethod` returns. Alternatively, you can make `isStarted` a data member. But you still have to make sure to join the thread before the `MyClass` destructor destroys it.

Comment: Deleting my answer and upvoting yours: didn't notice the absence of [tag:c++11].

Comment: when to call boost::bind and when not? we call it all over the place.

Comment: That takes care of the first problem. The second is that the write to `isStarted` in one thread and the read in another are not synchronized, so there is no guarantee that the second thread will see the updated value. In C++11 this would call for an `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA For example if you need a callable object, `boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind.....`

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right. In my case, that check is not critical but it should be synchronized anyway. If it is not synchronized, the value may not be the latest one is the ONLY issue or it may cause crash when both threads try to access the same location at the same time?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA - in C++11, the behavior without synchronization is undefined. In practice, there's a possibility that the thread will wait a **long** time for the updated value.

Comment: @sehe I was assuming that amongst all the `...` there was a join in `aMethod`.

Comment: Yes, **checkTimeoutThread** will exit before **isStarted** will be out of the scope. Otherwise I will use a class variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem (besides `std::ref` or `boost::ref` required to pass references to `thread`), is that you are passing a ***reference to a temporary***

```
MyClass::aMethod()
{
    ...
    bool isStarted = false;

}

/// Oops at the end of the method, `isStarted` no longer lives
```

Any access through the *stale reference* is Undefined Behaviour after control leaves `aMethod`

May I suggest using proper synchronization: **[See it Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b44b233206865b8)**

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mx;
    bool isStarted;
    std::thread worker;

    X() : isStarted(false) {}

    void aMethod()
    {
        worker = std::thread(&X::Worker, this);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        {
            std::cout << "signalling worker\n";
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mx);
            isStarted = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }

        worker.join();
        isStarted = false;
    }

    void Worker()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mx);
        std::cout << "worker ready\n";
        cv.wait(lock, [this] { return isStarted; });
        std::cout << "worker started\n";

        std::cout << "worker done\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X o;
    o.aMethod();
}
```

Note that

- if you `s/std/boost` you should be able to use this on C++03 compilers
- you ***almost*** don't need `isStarted` anymore in this case. I added it because of spurious wake-ups: [Why does pthread_cond_wait have spurious wakeups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups)