# Is waiting for an event subject to spurious wakeups?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

The MSDN page for [SleepConditionVariableCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301(v=vs.85).aspx) states that

> Condition variables are subject to spurious wakeups (those not
>   associated with an explicit wake) and stolen wakeups (another thread
>   manages to run before the woken thread). Therefore, you should recheck
>   a predicate (typically in a while loop) after a sleep operation
>   returns.

As a result the conditional wait has to be enclosed in a while loop i.e.

```
while (check_predicate())
{
    SleepConditionVariableCS(...)
}
```

If I were to use [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of Conditional Variables can I do away with the while loop while waiting ([WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)) for the event to be signaled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `WaitForSingleObject()`, there are no spurious wakeups, so you can eliminate the loop.

If you use `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` with `bAlertable=TRUE`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` with a wake mask, or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` with `bAlertable=TRUE` or a wake mask, then the wait can end on other conditions before the event is actually signaled.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea  why Conditional Variables are susceptible to spurious wakeups while Events don't have that problem?

Comment: @work.bin: it is just the way condition variables work in general. It is not limited to Microsoft's implementation, either.  [pthreads suffers from it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/), [so does STL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), and [boost, too](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). As to *WHY*, condition variables are *user-mode* objects, whereas events are *kernel* objects. The kernel does not have spurious wakes, but user-mode can, depending on thread scheduling and such.