# Does pthread_cond_wait lock the mutex und spurious wakeup

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

## TL;DR

I have a homework where i need to implement thread synchronization. During implementation i was concerned if `pthread_cond_wait()` also locks mutex if it spuriously wakes up and not just if it successfully wakes up.

## Task

The task is a worker/delivery problem where there are worker threads and management threads which provide orders for the workers. For this purpose there is an order list from which the workers get orders and the management thread deposits orders. The order list is a shared object and needs to be synchronized.

## My solution so far

I thought for this problem i need a monitor for the list to protect it from accesses on emptiness or from deposits when its full.

```
void deposit_order(order_list* ol, order* o){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(ol->mut_order_access));
    while(get_count(ol) >= MAX_ORDERS) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&(ol->cond_not_full), &(ol->mut_order_access));
    }

    ol->orders[ol->head] = o;
    ol->head = (ol->head+1)%MAX_ORDERS;
    ol->count++;
    
    pthread_cond_signal(&(ol->cond_not_empty));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ol->mut_order_access));
}

order* get_order(order_list* ol) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(ol->mut_order_access));
    while(get_count(ol) <= 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&(ol->cond_not_empty), &(ol->mut_order_access));
    }
    order* o;
    
    o = ol->orders[ol->tail];
    ol->tail = (ol->tail+1)%MAX_ORDERS;
    ol->count--;
    
    pthread_cond_signal(&(ol->cond_not_full));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ol->mut_order_access));
    return o;
}
```

I believe it is not that important what the structures contain since the topic is how to synchronize the access. Obviously the structure `order_list` holds a `mutex` and two condition variables to signal the other thread. So if a worker removes a task from the list, it signals "not empty" to the management thread so it can deposit an additional order. If the management deposits an order is signals "not empty" to the worker threads so one thread can remove an order from the list.

## My Concerns

So far so good but now i think there is that one event where the above solution may be critical and that is a "spurious wakeup". From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007503/mutex-status-after-spurious-wakeup) i learned that a thread can not spuriously wakeup if the corresponding mutex namely `mut_order_access` is locked by another thread. But what if there is for example only one order in the list so that `get_count(ol) >= MAX_ORDERS` is not fulfilled and a thread spuriously wakes up from the wait, checks the condition and marks it as not true and jumps out of the loop. Then another thread receives the signal and wakes up normally locking the mutex after the previous thread is already in the critical area. So now both threads would be in the critical area which would be a failure.

## Question

So the above could only happen if a thread does not lock the mutex when it spuriously wakes up so does it lock the mutex on spurious wakeup or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the conditions of spurious wakeup seems incorrect. Spurious wakeup has nothing to do with whether the mutex is locked by another thread. Unless you have a programming error (breaking the contracts of these functions, general memory corruption or other undefined behavior, etc.), `pthread_cond_wait` can never return without the mutex being held (locked) by the calling thread. In the event of a spurious wake, it still can't return until the mutex is re-acquired. Even in the event the waiter is cancelled with `pthread_cancel`, the cancellation cleanup handler cannot begin running until the mutex is re-acquired.

Comment: Thank that was exactly what i wanted to know. I knew a thread aquires the mutex on !successful! returning and can not return nor spuriously wake when the mutex is aquired by another thread but i wanted to know if it also aquires the mutex when it spouriously wakes and the mutex is still unlocked.

Answer (score 3):

A function that might return with a mutex locked or unlocked and that gave you no way to tell the difference would be entirely unusable. How could you possibly know whether to unlock the mutex or not?

The `pthread_cond_wait` function provides an atomic "unlock and wait" operation. It *always* re-acquires the mutex before returning. Assuming you don't violate any of its pre-conditions, of course.

You can think of it as a three-step process:

1. Atomic unlock and wait.
2. Either another thread signals/broadcasts the condition or there's a spurious wakeup.
3. Re-acquire the mutex

Only when all three steps are accomplished does `pthread_cond_wait` return. A spurious wakeup occurs when the wait ends without another thread sending a signal.

Comment: And that is my point when a spurious wakeup occurs is the mutex still aquired by the thread which wakes up?

Comment: @Yastanub If it wasn't, what could you possible do? You would have no idea whether you held the mutex or not, so no idea whether to call `pthread_mutex_unlock` or not. Such a defect would make `pthread_cond_wait` totally unusable. It would also require the implementation to somehow detect if a wakeup was spurious or not to know whether or not to re-acquire the mutex, which completely defeats the point of allowing spurious wakeups.

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` shall reacquire the mutex when it returns, including spurious wakeup.