# Where does the execution happen after a thread has called pthread_wait is now signalled?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void thread_1() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
       some_cond = true;        
      pthread_cond_signal(&cv);    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       
}
void thread_2() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);        
    while (!some_cond)              
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex); 
    printf("test"); // After signaling from thread_1, does this get ran after?
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       
}
```

Let's say that **thread_2** calls pthread_cond_wait.

**Thread_1** comes along then does pthread_cond_signal.

I understand that **thread_2** will be blocked when pthread_cond_wait is called, and unlock its mutex.
However, I am confuse on which line of code will run in **thread_2** after **thread_1** calls signal.

In **thread_2** when its woken up, does it start from the beginning where thread_2 now has access to the mutex, then locks it, then checks the while condition again, and sees that its true now and prints test?

Or does thread_2 get access to its mutex, then locks it and then the **print("test")** is ran after (ignoring the while condition)?

Comment: Why not use a debugger to find out? Or you output some debug statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The several other examples are all good, but they also all seem to gloss over what I take to be the OP's key point of confusion.

> I am confuse on which line of code will run in thread_2 after thread_1 calls signal.

There is no magic here.  `pthread_cond_wait()` is a function, and it behaves like one.  When its wait is over, and it has reacquired the mutex, it *returns* to its caller.  Control proceeds normally from there, just as it would after any other function call returns.

In this particular case, the function call is the sole statement in the body of a `while` loop, so the next thing that happens after the call returns will be the `while` condition being reevaluated.

Note that `pthread_cond_wait`'s caller can and should check the return value to catch and handle cases where it indicates that an error has occurred, just as should be done with other functions that indicate error conditions via their return values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific line of code that is run in another thread when one calls `pthread_cond_signal`. If you want specific lines to be run in a specific order, you must put all those lines into the path of one thread.

When `pthread_cond_signal` is called, the other thread could be doing almost anything. One thing we know is that,
because the signal call is inside the mutex, the other thread is not in the mutex. We can label the places where the other can be:

```
void thread_2() {
    // (A) Either here, or earlier.
 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);        
    while (!some_cond)              
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex); // (B) Or here. 
    printf("test"); // After signaling from thread_1, does this get ran after?
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  

    // (C) Or else here, or farther 
}
```

The other thread can be at `C` only if `some_cond` was already true. If `some_cond` is assumed false, we can forget about `C`.

If `A` is the case, the thread is either executing code before the `pthread_mutex_lock` (we can call that `A1`), or else it has hit the lock and is now waiting for the mutex (`A2`).

The thread which calls `pthread_cond_signal` owns the mutex, and continues to do so after making this call. So it's possible that the other thread is in `A1`, and proceeds to `A2` (waiting on the mutex).

If the thread is in `B`: waiting on the condition variable, it's possible that the signal will wake it up. Before returning from `pthread_cond_wait`, it has to re-acquire the mutex, so it can get stuck waiting there.  In any case, in the `B` state, the other thread cannot return from the `pthread_cond_wait` call until the first thread does the `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

It's possible that the other thread is in the `A1` state (not yet reached the mutex), and the signaler completes everything: sets the variable, signals, and releases the mutex. Then the other thread will grab the mutex without waiting, see that the condition is true, and leave the mutex. The signaling is then irrelevant, since `pthread_cond_wait` is never called.

If you're doing programming with shared variables and explicit synchronization primitives like mutexes and conditions, you have to reason about all the cases which can happen: all the relevant states in which the other thread(s) can be.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am confuse on which line of code will run in thread_2 after thread_1 calls signal.

Actually, after the call of `pthread_cond_signal` from thread_1, nothing will happen, because thread_1 still have the mutex lock. The next instruction on thread_1 is `pthread_mutex_unlock`. The thread_2 will then stop blocking in `pthread_cond_wait` and atomically `acquire` the lock. The while condition will then check the condition, break and print "test".

Comment: When doing a pthread_cond_wait, is it better to have a while(!some_cond) loop, or would an if(!some_cond) work too? I've seen some examples where it uses the if statement as oppose to the while loop.

Comment: Yes it's recommended to have a while with a condition, because the API does not guarantee pthread_cond_signal to be the only reason for pthread_cond_wait to be unblocked. They may have some other reasons for pthread_cond_wait to unblock. They name that Spurious wakeups. You can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups#:~:text=Spurious%20wakeups%20from%20the%20pthread_cond_timedwait%20%28%29%20or%20pthread_cond_wait,can%20return%20even%20if%20you%20haven%27t%20signaled%20it.

Comment: Re, "after the call of pthread_cond_signal from thread_1, nothing will happen." Actually, something very important will happen. It won't be visible to the program, but it's important none the less.  After the condition variable is signalled, the `pthread_cond_wait()` call will  stop waiting for the signal, and it will start waiting to re-acquire the mutex. It still will be waiting, but now it will be waiting for something different from what it previously was awaiting.

Comment: Actually, `pthread_cond_signal` will not do much, this is the following instruction `pthread_mutex_unlock` of thread 1 which will allow the thread 2 to acquire the lock. My answer seems pretty correct.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
void thread_1() {
```

and

```
void thread_2() {
```

Those are NOT valid signatures for thread functions!  perhaps you meant:

```
void * thread_1( void *arg )
```

and

```
void * thread_2( void *arg )
```

Also, running off the end of a thread function is not valid.  Suggest the last statement in each thread be:

```
pthread_exit( void );
```

There is no guarantee as to which thread runs first.  If `thread_2()` runs first, then the mutex will be locked and thread_2() will be waiting, forever, for the pthread_condition(), but since `thread_1()` will be immediately blocked trying to obtain the mutex lock.  NOTHING (more) will be executed in those threads.

in general, the function: `pthread_wait()` is called in the same part of the executable as called the function: `pthread_create()`.  That halts the calling code until some thread exits (which, in the above scenario no thread will ever exit