# C code for producer-consumer counter unexpected output

Tags: c

I am creating a simple counter using a producer-consumer approach to signal when one thread is done so the other can run, which allows them to alternate. When I run the code, the count is printed out 10 times as expected from 0-10. But in between each print of the count I get a dozen of prints for locks and unlocks and signaling which leads me to think I have my code set up wrong.

Shouldn't there only be 1 lock, unlock, and signal for each iteration on the consumer and producer ends? Example output is below:

```
myCount: 6 -> 7
Producer: signaling myCond1
Producer: waiting on myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
myCount: 7 -> 8
Producer: signaling myCond1
Producer: waiting on myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
myCount: 8 -> 9
Producer: signaling myCond1
Producer: waiting on myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked
myCount: 9 -> 10
Producer: signaling myCond1
Producer: waiting on myCond2
CONSUMER: myMutex locked
CONSUMER: signaling myCond2
Producer: myMutex unlocked
Producer: myMutex locked
PROGRAM END
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Global variables
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t myCond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t myCond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int myCount = 0;

// Function prototypes
void* producerThread(void* arg);
void* consumerThread(void* arg);

int main() {
    // Create consumer thread
    pthread_t consumer;
    printf("PROGRAM START\n");

    if (pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, consumerThread, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("Error creating consumer thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Run the producer thread
    producerThread(NULL);

    // Wait for the consumer thread to finish
    pthread_join(consumer, NULL);

    printf("PROGRAM END\n");

    return 0;
}

void* producerThread(void* arg) {
    while (1) {
        printf("Producer: myMutex locked\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        
        if (myCount >= 10) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
            break;  // Terminate the program when myCount reaches 10
        }

        myCount++;
        printf("myCount: %d -> %d\n", myCount - 1, myCount);

        // Signal the consumer that a new value is available
        printf("Producer: signaling myCond1\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&myCond1);

        printf("Producer: waiting on myCond2\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&myCond2, &myMutex);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        printf("Producer: myMutex unlocked\n");
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* consumerThread(void* arg) {
    printf("CONSUMER THREAD CREATED\n");

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        printf("CONSUMER: myMutex locked\n");

        // Wait for the producer to signal that a new value is available
        while (myCount == 0) {
            printf("CONSUMER: waiting on myCond1\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&myCond1, &myMutex);
        }

        // Signal the producer that the value has been consumed
        printf("CONSUMER: signaling myCond2\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&myCond2);

        if (myCount >= 10) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
            break;  // Terminate the program when myCount reaches 0
        }
        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
        printf("CONSUMER: myMutex unlocked\n");
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your consumer only ever enters a condition-wait when `myCount` is equal to zero. As soon as it encounters a non-zero value, the consumer becomes greedy and will constantly spin on acquiring the mutex and signalling.

Perhaps you want to keep a local copy of the last value processed by the consumer and enter your condition-wait when that value has not changed since the previous iteration:

```
void* consumerThread(void* arg) {
    printf("CONSUMER THREAD CREATED\n");

    int lastCount = 0;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        printf("CONSUMER: myMutex locked\n");

        // Wait for the producer to signal that a new value is available
        while (myCount == lastCount) {
            printf("CONSUMER: waiting on myCond1\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&myCond1, &myMutex);
        }
        lastCount++;

        // Signal the producer that the value has been consumed
        printf("CONSUMER: signaling myCond2\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&myCond2);

        if (lastCount>= 10) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
            break;
        }
        
        printf("CONSUMER: unlocking myMutex\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

On a separate note, you have a race condition in both functions where you print the message about *unlocking* the mutex. Because you do this after unlocking, the other thread can acquire the mutex and print messages before that code is even hit.

I recommend you move the `printf` to happen before releasing the mutex to avoid additional confusion. Note that I've done this in my code example. You should make a similar change in the producer function.

Be aware also that the producer is susceptible to spurious wake-ups. You are assuming that the `pthread_cond_wait` will only wake up when the condition variable is signalled. That's not the case. Read this for more information: [Why does pthread_cond_wait have spurious wakeups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups)

To solve that, and create a true ping-pong dependency between your producer and consumer, you can make that `lastCount` variable global as well, and run an inner while-loop in the producer in the same way as the consumer:

```
while (myCount != lastCount) {
    printf("Producer: waiting on myCond2\n");
    pthread_cond_wait(&myCond2, &myMutex);
}
```