# In monitors,after entering thread on wait should it again check the condition?

Tags: multithreading

In monitors, if a thread A goes to wait as some condition is false and if other thread B signals as condition is true and resets the condition so condition becomes false again. When thread A resumes execution should it check the condition? or should it proceed after that?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you want thread A to stop if thread B resets the event, then make your code do that. What you're asking is very unclear. A code sample with a more detailed explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages/environments your approach is wrong, because it does not take into account of **spurious wakeups**.

When waiting on a condition, in many languages/environments have to consider the possibility that you will be woken up without anybody explicitly sending you a signal. This is called spurious wakeup (see e.g. [Do spurious wakeups actually happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen)).

If the signaling thread resets the condition, you cannot distinguish between a proprer signal and a spurious one, so you should not do that.