# Guaranteeing Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

May I, please, know if the below program guarantees a deadlock? Given below are details:
Threads: process1 and process2.
Objects: scanner and printer.
process1 locks on both scanner and printer, but gives up scanner. process2 locks scanner but cannot acquire printer because process1 has locked it. Perhaps my thread concepts are unclear, but may I, please, know where am I going wrong?

```
class DeadLock extends Thread {

    //creating a scanner object
    private static Object scanner = new Object();

    //creating a printer object
    private static Object printer = new Object();

    //the process name
    private String processName;

    //initializes process2 is not created yet
    private boolean process2IsCreated = false;

    /**
     * the constructor which sets string to process1 or 2
     * @param string
     */
    public DeadLock(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.processName  = string;
    }

    /**
     * deadlock() for process1
     */
    public void deadlock1() {

        //process1 locks scanner
        synchronized (scanner) {

            //process1 locks printer, too
            synchronized (printer) {

                //create process2 after process1
                if(process2IsCreated == false && processName.equals("process1")) {
                    new DeadLock("process2").start();
                    process2IsCreated = true;
                }

                try {
                    //process1 is waiting on scanner and releases its monitor. 
                    //After regaining access, process1 tries to acquire scanner
                    //but cannot do so because process2 has locked it already.
                    //. . .too late, process1!
                    scanner.wait();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * deadlock() for process2
     */
    public void deadlock2() {

        //process2 locks scanner
        synchronized (scanner) {

            //process2 notifies process1 which is waiting on scanner
            scanner.notify();

            //process2 locks printer, but cannot lock printer because process1 has it
            //. . .too late, process2!
            synchronized (printer) {
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * both threads are scheduled to execute run()
     */
    public void run() {

        //if process1 then enter deadlock1()
        if(processName.equals ("process1")) deadlock1();

        //if process 2 then enter deadlock2()
        else deadlock2();
    }

    /**
     * the main method which creates thread process1
     * @param a
     */
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new DeadLock("process1").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question? why your program still finishes and is not locked?

Comment: My question is whether this program guarantees a deadlock? If no, may I, please, have an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working for me, here is the Thread Dump in Intellij:

[image]

Comment: I am starting the second thread after guaranteeing the first thread enters deadlock1()

Comment: Pardon, how do you start it? In a separate process?

Comment: Basically, I am enforcing thread process1 to start first and then creating thread process2 in a method deadlock1(). I start thread process1 first so that it is guaranteed thread process1 runs first and enters deadlock1() where the next thread process2 is created and scheduled to execute run(). Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed the line with a help of @user2994258.

Comment: Hey, you have created a perfectly working deadlock, congrats! will attach a screenshot in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

see this.. here 2nd thread is being started

```
//create process2 after process1
                if(process2IsCreated == false && processName.equals("process1")) {
                    new DeadLock("process2").start();   <---------------HERE
                    process2IsCreated = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess, the flow is.. 
Thread 1 : takes scanner lock
Thread 1: takes printer lock
Thread 1: creates and starts 2nd thread

Possible flow: 

Thread 2 : Starts, executes run and goes into deadlock2()
Thread 1: waits for object scanner
Thread 2: Enters lock Scanner 
Thread 2: Notifies lock scanner
Thread 2: stuck as it cant get into printer block as Thread 1 has it
Thread 1: Is waiting for Thread 2 to leave scanner block which it does not.

Result: Thread 2 can not have Printer & Thread 1 can not start executing as Thread 2 even when it is notified scanner , has not left Scanner block.

This is not a proper deadlock as thread 1 has not returned for execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Java's synchronization primitives, but to me it looks like:

Thread 1 locks scanner.
Thread 1 locks printer.
Thread 2 is started.
Thread 1 temporarily releases scanner, sleeps waiting for a notification.
Thread 2 locks scanner.
Thread 2 posts the notification.
Thread 2 blocks on printer.

Thread 1 never wakes up because Thread 2 never releases scanner.
Thread 2 never wakes up because Thread 1 is not yet done with printer.

My guess is that you're wrong in making Thread 1 sleep in the first place. It has acquired both resources, what else is it waiting for?

There's also the possibility that you're overusing synchronization; normally, simple `synchronized` blocks (monitor) or `wait`/`notify` calls (semaphore) might be enough. You're using both.

I *think* the rule of thumb here, is, "if you're going to use `wait`/`notify`, wrap them in minimal `synchronized` blocks". Your scanner block in Thread 2 extends past the `notify` call, into the printer block.

--
To clarify:

```
synchronized (x) { A; }
synchronized (x) { B; }
```

is (uses) a monitor, for when you don't want A and B to execute at the same time.

```
synchronized (x) { x.wait(); } B;
A; synchronized (x) { x.notify(); }
```

uses a semaphore to make sure A executes before B.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an almost perfect deadlock example for the following reason (Oracle wait() doc):

> The thread releases
>   ownership of **this** monitor and waits until another thread notifies
>   threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up[...]

So the monitor scanner is released, but the monitor printer is not released. This is why you should not synchronize twice.

There is only one catch to your code and that is [spurious wakeups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen). It can happen (although it is very unlikely), that the wait call suddenly wakes up with no one having called notify ever. This is more a cause of the lock implementation in the OS than having anything to do with Java, but running on the right OS your deadlock might eventually wake up, after a few days, month or years.