# JAVA wait/sleep not to be interrupted by other thread

Tags: java, concurrency

I need your help.

I got 2 JAVA classes. In one class there is a FIFO list/queue, both classes have to access this list concurrent. The list is in class1. Class1 uses the addElementToEndOfQueue. Class2 uses getValueOfQueue to get und remove the head of the queue.

```
public static synchronized String getValueOfQueue(){
    return queueSend.poll(); 
}

public synchronized boolean addValueToQueue(String s){
    Boolean blnReturn = queueSend.offer(s);
    class2.interrupt();
    return blnReturn;
}
```

Class2 tries and takes the head value of the queue, if the queue is null than strValue is null and the thread should wait till he is interrupted bei addValueToQueue:

```
while(true){
 String strValue = class1.getValueOfQueue();
 if (strValue == null) {
            try {
                wait();}
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                continue;}
// do things
}
```

My problem is now that if have to wait/sleep in the while loop (to simulate a delay). If i use sleep or wait than it could happen that addValueToQueue interrupts me and I don't want that. I want the programm to wait the given time and not be interrupted. How can I do this? Or should I use a completely other approach as I am using right now?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html It may solve your problem without the need to synchronize it yourself.

Comment: You should be using wait() and notify(), not sleep() and interrupt(). This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: Another side comment: be prepared for [spurious wakeups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen) in those situations.

Comment: @EJP what can I wait for? I should wait for getValueOfQueue() returns a value != null but how can I do that?