# predicate for condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, condition-variable

I am new to multi threading. While writing multi threaded code in C++11 using condition variable , I use the following construct

```
while(predicate) {
    cond_var.wait(&lock);
}
```

However, I have been reading Deitel's third edition book on operating systems(chp 6) where the following construct is being used

```
if(predicate) {
    cond_var.wait(&lock);
}
```

So, what's the difference? Why isn't the book using while? Isn't spurious call an issue?

Comment: While concurrency with condition variables is a suitable topic for [cs.se], your question is really more about how the C++ implementation behaves. This is a programming question, more suitable for [so], so I am migrating it there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spurious wakeup is always a potential issue.  For example, look at the answers here: [Do spurious wakeups actually happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen).  Perhaps Deitel's code is part of a larger loop that can help them deal with the spurious wakeup?  Or maybe it's just a typo.

In any case, there's never a (good) reason not to use your construct, and in fact the `wait` function has a variant that does it for you (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

```
template< class Predicate >
void wait( std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock, Predicate pred );
```

which is equivalent to:

```
while (!pred()) {
     wait(lock);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

People seem to be dealing with spurious wakeups exclusively, but there is a more fundamental reason why a `while` or an `if` is to be used in monitor procedures. 
We would have to choose one or the other even if there were no spurious wakeups because monitor implementations may choose from a number of different signaling disciplines.

The following paper describes these

> John H. Howard. 1976. Signaling in monitors. In Proceedings of the 2nd international conference on Software engineering (ICSE '76). IEEE Computer Society Press, Los Alamitos, CA, USA, 47-52.

The point is that a monitor can be used by at most one process at a time, and there is a conflict when a waiting process is being woken up (signaled) by another process from inside the monitor. The problem is: which process may continue executing inside the monitor?

There are a number of different disciplines. The one originally proposed is the so called **signal and wait**, where the signaled process continues immediately (the signaler has to wait). Using this discipline the

```
if ( predicate) {
  cond_var.wait( &lock);
}
```

form can be used because the predicate must be true after waiting (provided it is true at the time of signaling)

Another discipline is **signal and continue**, where the signaling process continues, the signaled is put into an entry queue of the monitor. Using this discipline necessitates the use of the

```
while ( predicate) {
  cond_var.wait( &lock);
}
```

form because predicate can be invalidated by the time the signaled process gets a chance to execute, so it has to retest the condition.

Comment: But OP is asking about C++11 condition variables, which are signal-and-continue.  `if` might work with signal-and-wait, but it's not relevant with C++11 cvars.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: OP asked about why the Deitel book contains examples using `if` and specifically about what the difference is between using `if` and `while`. I think my answer is definitely relevant to that question.