# How to forcefully make one thread to be executed first in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have created two threads in c. I want to execute two separate functions by each threads. How to make one particular thread to be executed first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* function_1(void* p)
{
   // statements
}

void* function_2(void* p)
{
   // statements
}

int main(void)
{
   pthread_t id1;
   pthread_t id2;

   pthread_create(&id1, NULL, function_1, NULL);
   pthread_create(&id2, NULL, function_2, NULL);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

How do I make function_1 to be executed before function_2 when the program starts?

Comment: Is it worth asking for a sequential execution in a multithreaded program ? It would be better to make a single threaded program calling both functions sequentially.

Comment: If you really need to synchronize the threads, you can use a pthreads [condition variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) together with a pthreads [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 5):

Change your main function to look like this:

```
int main(void) {
    function_1(NULL);
    function_2(NULL);
}
```

No joke! If it's important for `function_2()` to not start until `function_1()` is finished, then that's how to do it. Any time you need a program to do certain things in a certain, strict order; the best way to achieve that is to do all of the things in the same thread.

Threads *do* need to "sync up" with each other from time to time (e.g., it doesn't make any sense for a consumer to take something out of a queue before a producer puts something in to the queue to be taken), but if your threads don't spend *most* of their time working *independently* of each other, then you probably aren't getting any benefit from using multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

@SolomonSlow has already stated the obvious. Why have several threads if you want sequential execution?

Bust just for completeness:

```
pthread_create(&id1, NULL, function_1, NULL);
pthread_join(id1, NULL);
pthread_create(&id2, NULL, function_2, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in one of the other answers, your problem is likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It would probably be best to not use multithreading at all in such a situation, but use a single thread instead.

If you really do want to use threads, then, as already stated in one of the other answers, using `pthread_join` would probably be the best solution for the code you posted in your question.

However, if you merely want to ensure that the code in `function_2` is not executed before another thread has finished executing `function_1`, and don't want to wait for the thread executing `function_1` to terminate (e.g. because the thread is supposed to do something else after calling `function_1`), then I recommend that you synchronize the threads using a pthreads [condition variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) together with a pthreads [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

The following example adds code to the end of `function_1` to signal the other thread that it may now proceed with `function_2`. It also adds code to the start of `function_2` which waits for this signal to be sent.

Here is the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct sync_data
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    volatile int predicate;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

void* function_1(void* p)
{
    // the function's main code goes here

    //signal to other thread that it may now proceed
    struct sync_data *psd = p;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &psd->mutex );
    psd->predicate = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &psd->mutex );
    pthread_cond_signal( &psd->cond );
}

void* function_2(void* p)
{
    //wait for signal from other thread
    struct sync_data *psd = p;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &psd->mutex );
    while ( !psd->predicate )
        pthread_cond_wait( &psd->cond, &psd->mutex );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &psd->mutex );

    // the function's main code goes here
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sync_data sd;
    pthread_t id1;
    pthread_t id2;

    //init sync_data struct members
    pthread_mutex_init( &sd.mutex, NULL );
    sd.predicate = 0;
    pthread_cond_init( &sd.cond, NULL );

    //create and start both threads
    pthread_create( &id1, NULL, function_1, &sd );
    pthread_create( &id2, NULL, function_2, &sd );

    //wait for all threads to finish
    pthread_join(id1, NULL);
    pthread_join(id2, NULL);

    //cleanup
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &sd.mutex );
    pthread_cond_destroy( &sd.cond );
}
```

Comment: Nice, but "predicate" is a funny name for a boolean _variable_. "Predicate" sounds like a _function_ that would compute a boolean value. Many programmers would call that variable something like, `flag`. A few might call it something like, `safe_for_func2_to_go` or `func1_has_done_its_dirty_work`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I called it "predicate" because it is the predicate of the condition variable. [Every condition variable has a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22837254/12149471). You are right that in larger programs with several predicate variables, it would be more meaningful not to simply give predicate variables the name `predicate`, but rather a name which is more descriptive, such as `safe_for_func2_to_go`. However, in this simple case it seemed appropriate to me.