# What situations may cause InterruptedException in independed thread?

Tags: java, thread-safety

In my app I have this simple piece of clock code:

```
while(!clockRunning){
    time++;
    repaint();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
}catch (InterruptedException e){}
```

and I began curious what situation may cause exception above.

Comment: [Spurious wakeups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen). More importantly you are either sleeping the EDT or calling `paint()` from a `Thread` that is not the EDT. Both are **very wrong**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the
[Thread Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) :

> if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted
>   status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

basicly when another thread calls this threads interrupt method