# take() and put() implementation in BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

I understand the theory and the concept of BlockingQueue, but when I look at the [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java.html) for LinkedBlockingQueue. I don't get why we use a `while` loop keep trying and wait in line 8 in the `take()` method (same for `put()`). I thought an `if` check would be suffice since the `signalNotEmpty()` which is being called from `put()` only signal one in line 27 but not all, so only one waiting thread will be woken up, right ? I am wondering do I miss anything ? Can someone explain why we use `while` instead of `if`

Here's the code fragment

```
 1 public E take() throws InterruptedException {
 2      E x;
 3      int c = -1;
 4      final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
 5      final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
 6      takeLock.lockInterruptibly();
 7      try {
 8          while (count.get() == 0) {
 9               notEmpty.await();
10          }
11          x = dequeue();
12          c = count.getAndDecrement();
13          if (c > 1)
14             notEmpty.signal();
15      } finally {
16          takeLock.unlock();
17      }
18      if (c == capacity)
19          signalNotFull();
20      return x;
21 }
22
23 private void signalNotEmpty() {
24     final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
25     takeLock.lock();
26     try {
27         notEmpty.signal();
28     } finally {
29         takeLock.unlock();
30     }
31 }
```

and what happen if we change line 8 to

```
if(count.get() == 0) { 
     notEmpty.await();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because of **spurious wakeups**. Please read the javadoc of Condition Class
also see [Do spurious wakeups actually happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen)

```
* <h3>Implementation Considerations</h3>
 *
 * <p>When waiting upon a {@code Condition}, a &quot;<em>spurious
 * wakeup</em>&quot; is permitted to occur, in
 * general, as a concession to the underlying platform semantics.
 * This has little practical impact on most application programs as a
 * {@code Condition} should always be waited upon in a loop, testing
 * the state predicate that is being waited for.  An implementation is
 * free to remove the possibility of spurious wakeups but it is
 * recommended that applications programmers always assume that they can
 * occur and so always wait in a loop.
```

Comment: AKA  'synchro on Linux is broken by design'.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is "spurious wakeup". See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

Answer (score -1):

This is to catch a race condition, if multiple threads were waiting and they all woke up, some other thread may have already taken semaphore count, so each thread needs to check again.