# Manually inflicted spurious wakeup on Linux?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is Manually inflicted spurious wakeup on Linux possible? I want to experiment with some Java concurrency. I heard that it is possible, but very unlikely. Still for testing purposes it will be very beneficial.

Comment: what do you need to test? Usually we shouldn't care about the reason of wakeup anyway.

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1051816/3440745) to the first question in "Related" section states that spurious wakeups on Linux are possible and give a way to generate them: `If a Linux process is signaled its waiting threads will each enjoy a nice, hot spurious wakeup.`