# how to prevent spurious wake ups in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read there may occure spurious wake ups in which thread waiting can wake up without notify and notifyAll calls, how can we prevent such wake ups?
[Do spurious wakeups actually happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do spurious wakeups actually happen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen)

Comment: You can _not_ prevent them.  That's _one_ reason why, when ever a `wait()` call returns, your code must check to see whether the event it's waiting for has happened or not.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html