# Different behavior when implementing Runnable instead of extending Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, race-condition, synchronized

So here's the code. 
Basically if we change the ReadCalculation and Calculator classes to extend Thread instead of implementing Runnable we would need to instantiate these classes and pass them to a new thread object or just call start() on them.

```
Calculator calc = new Calculator();
new ReadCalculation(calc).start();
new ReadCalculation(calc).start();
calc.start();
```

Nothing special so far.. But when you execute this tiny program, there's a huge chance that your threads will stay blocked "Waiting for calculation..." if we're going over the Runnable implementation over extending the Thread class.

If we're extending the Thread class instead of implementing Runnable the behavior is correct without any sign of race condition.
Any ideas on which could be the source of this behavior?

```
public class NotifyAllAndWait {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        Thread th01 = new Thread(new ReadCalculation(calc));
        th01.start();
        Thread th02 = new Thread(new ReadCalculation(calc));
        th02.start();

        Thread calcThread = new Thread(calc);
        calcThread.start();
    }
}

class ReadCalculation implements Runnable {

    private Calculator calc = null;
    ReadCalculation(Calculator calc) {
        this.calc = calc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (calc) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Waiting for calculation...");
                calc.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Total: " + calc.getTotal());
        }
    }
}

class Calculator implements Runnable {
    private int total = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " RUNNING CALCULATION!");
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 2){
                total = total + i;
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't cite any part of language or JVM specification, that may be in play here, but the most likely practical reason is that source code of `Thread` takes awful lot of locks on both `Thread.class` and current `Thread` instance. You lock on Calculator instance both from inside and outside of `calc`. Those locks may not interfere with locking inside `Thread` when you use a dedicated target Runnable (just checked: no code within Android Thread implementation appears to lock on the passed Runnable), but would certainly affect execution order when you extend Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `implements Runnable` version, at least, you do nothing to ensure that the `ReadCalculation` threads reach the `wait()` before the `Calculator` thread enters its `synchronized` block. If the `Calculator` thread enters its `synchronized` block first, then it will call `notifyAll()` before the `ReadCalculation` threads have called `wait()`. And if that happens, then the `notifyAll()` is a no-op, and the `ReadCalculation` threads will wait forever. (This is because `notifyAll()` only cares about threads that are *already* waiting on an object; it does *not* set any sort of indicator on the object that could be detected by subsequent calls to `wait()`.)

To fix that, you could add a property to `Calculator` that can be used to check for done-ness, and only call `wait()` if the `Calculator` is *not* done:

```
if(! calc.isCalculationDone()) {
    calc.wait();
}
```

(Note that, in order to completely avoid the race condition, it's important that the entire `if`-statement be *inside* the `synchronized` block, and that `Calculator` set this property *inside* the `synchronized` block that calls `notifyAll()`. Do you see why?)

(By the way, Peter Lawrey's comment that "a thread can easily to your 100 iterations before the other threads have even started" is highly misleading, since in your program the 100 iterations all happen *after* `Calculator` has entered its `synchronized` block. Since the `ReadCalculation` threads are blocked from entering their `synchronized` blocks and calling `calc.wait()` while `Calculator` is in its `synchronized` block, it shouldn't matter whether this is 1 iteration, 100 iterations, or 1,000,000 iterations, unless it has interesting optimization effects that could change the timing of the program *before* that point.)

---

You haven't posted the entire `extends Thread` version, but if I understand correctly what it looks like, then it actually still has the same race condition. However, it's in the nature of race conditions that minor changes can massively affect the likelihood of misbehavior. You still need to fix the race condition even if it never seems to actually misbehave, because it's almost certain that it will misbehave occasionally if you run the program enough times.

I don't have a good explanation for why the misbehavior seems to happen much more often with one approach than the other; but as user1643723 comments above, the `extends Thread` approach implies that lots of code *other* than yours is also likely to lock on your `Calculator` instance; and this could well have an effect of some sort. But honestly, I don't think it's worth worrying too much about the reasons why a race condition might cause a misbehavior more often or less often; we have to fix it regardless, so, end of story.

---

Incidentally:

- Above, I used `if(! calc.isCalculationDone())`; but it's actually a best practice to always wrap calls to `wait()` in an appropriate `while`-loop, so really you should write `while(! calc.isCalculationDone())`. There are two major reasons for this:

  - In nontrivial programs, you don't necessarily know *why* `notifyAll()` was called, or even if you do, you don't know whether that reason is still applicable by the time the waiting thread has actually woken up and regained the `synchronized`-lock. It makes it much easier to reason about the correctness of your `notify()`/`wait()` interactions if you use the `while(not_ready_to_proceed()) { wait(); }` structure to express the idea of `wait_until_ready_to_proceed()`, rather than just writing `wait()` and trying to make sure that nothing will ever cause it to return while we're not ready.
  - On some operating systems, sending a signal to the process will wake up all threads that are `wait()`-ing. This is called a *spurious wakeup*; see ["Do spurious wakeups actually happen?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-actually-happen) for more information. So a thread may get woken up even if no other thread called `notify()` or `notifyAll()`.
- The `for`-loop in `Calculator.run()` shouldn't be in the `synchronized` block, because it doesn't require any synchronization, so the contention is not needed. In your small program, it doesn't actually make a difference (since none of the other threads actually has anything to do at that point anyway), but the best practice is always to try to minimize the amount of code inside `synchronized` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a `wait()` this needs to be in a loop after a state change you performed the `notify()` block. e.g.

```
// when notify
changed = true;
x.notifyAll();

// when waiting
while(!changed)
    x.wait();
```

If you don't do this you will run into issue such as wait() waking spuriously or notify() being lost.

Note: a thread can easily to your 100 iterations before the other threads have even started. It is possible that pre-creating the `Thread` object makes enough of a difference to the performance to change the outcome in your case.

Comment: As correct as it can be, your first statement looks irrelevant here.

Comment: @user1643723 happy to be corrected with a better answer which explains the OPs problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey care to elaborate on "notify being lost" part? [JLS chapter about notify()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.2) does not mention anything like that.

Comment: @user1643723 The Javadoc states https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll-- "Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor." so if no threads are waiting, nothing happens. Similarly notify() states "If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened." If you notify() when nothing is waiting, no state is changed. any wait() after it could wait() forever.

Comment: Sure, no one is objecting to that here. But the question is asking why the deadlock *does not appear to happen* in one specific case. The first part of your statement makes it sound like spurious wake-ups may be the cause, but why would the code behave differently depending on small code change? AFAIK, there may be [OS-level and hardware-level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050592/1643723) reasons for spurious wake-ups, such as receiving Linux signals etc. Those don't exactly fit in described pattern.