# Does a thread run this.notifyAll when its run method is over?

Tags: java, multithreading

This piece of code will not be blocked. Though main method will wait at thread, but it seems this object will invoke this.notifyAll?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        synchronized (thread) {
            thread.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("stop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The main-thread is in `wait` and the program is stuck as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering just the question in your title:

> Does a thread run this.notifyAll when its run method is over?

[The documentation for Oracle's Java 12 edition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) says, Yes, the `join()` method calls `wait()` waiting for a notification that the thread has terminated.

**But note!** It also says, "It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances."  It also says, "...*this* implementation..." Some other Java Run-time Environment might implement `thread.join()` in a different way, and a program that depends on a `Thread` object to be `notify()`ed when the thread terminates might not work if you run it on the other JRE.

---

Also, see @akuzminykh's answer. Summary:

The `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods *do not do anything at all* unless some other thread *already is waiting* in a `wait()` call.  If your program terminates by itself, that's nice, but you should not depend on it to terminate by itself. By the time the main thread calls `thread.wait()` there's no reason to *expect* that any other thread will call `thread.notify()`, and so there's no reason to expect that the `thread.wait()` won't wait forever.

---

> I'm just curious about the mechanism of `join`...

Take a look at the source code for the OpenJDK version of the `Thread` class.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java

The `join()` method just calls `join(0)`, and in the special case where the `millis` argument to `join(long millis)` is zero, all it does is this:

```
while (isAlive()) {
    wait();
}
```

In other words, all it does is `wait()` until the thread is not alive.

Note! You won't find the `notify()` call in the `Thread.java` source file. The notification happens somewhere else (maybe native code?) after the thread's `run()` method either returns or throws an exception.

Comment: I'm just curious about the mechanism of join, thank you so much

Comment: @ChuangHou, see what I added to the end of my answer, above.

Answer (score -1):

*This answer assumes that the given code is the one you've used and it actually does finish when you run it.*

The given code is not "supposed" to finish under "normal" circumstances. As the `wait` happens after `join`, it's impossible that the terminated thread `notify`s the main-thread somehow. So why does it finish?

You could be a "victim" of a [spurious wake-up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050592/12323248). This happens when the JVM wakes up a thread "without a reason" from the programmer's perspective. Check out the [related JLS part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) about `wait`:

> Implementations are permitted, although not encouraged, to perform "spurious wake-ups", that is, to remove threads from wait sets and thus enable resumption without explicit instructions to do so.

> Notice that this provision necessitates the Java coding practice of using wait only within loops that terminate only when some logical condition that the thread is waiting for holds.

*Notice that this is one of the reasons you should always use `wait` in a loop.*

In other words: A JVM is allowed to wake up a thread by itself. This can have e.g. performance reasons. Notice that there are many JVM implementations out there. The code you write is Java but the virtual machines that run the code can have different behaviours. Notice that Java runs on different platforms, hardware and so on, which makes different JVM implementations/behaviours necessary.

A spurious wake-up is a speciality and rather rare. It should definitely not occur in simple code like this. But it seems that this is the case here.

---

*Just to be complete:*

Yes, a thread calls `this.notifyAll` when it finishes. Check out [`Thread#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

> [...] As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. [...]

But as already explained, it's not the cause for the effect that you're essentially asking about.