# After executing wait(), how long does a thread wait if it does not get notified from other threads?

Tags: java, java-threads

In the below example, as the main-thread is not getting notified from the child thread, it should wait forever. But the main-thread is getting executed and the output of the below example is:

```
c
l
total: 19900
```

Why is the main-thread getting executed?

```java
public class ThreadX extends Thread {
    static int total = 0;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                total = total + i;
            }
            System.out.println("c");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadX t = new ThreadX();

        t.start();
        synchronized (t) {
            t.wait();
            System.out.println("l");
        }

        System.out.println("total: " + total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Looks like the runtime sent a `notify` to your thread object. Better use a dedicated monitor object not something that might already participate in notification for other purposes.

Answer (score 9):

## Answer to the question-body

Check out [`Thread#join(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)):

> [...] As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. [...]

Notice that `Thread#join()` calls that function with `0`, which means forever.

> [...] A timeout of 0 means to wait forever.

So in your case here `t` just calls `notifyAll` when it terminates, which notifies the main-thread that is waiting on `t`.

---

This unintuitive behaviour is the reason why they write the following in the documentation:

> It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

## Answer to the question-title

Check out [`Object#wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)) (or [JLS (17.2.1. Wait)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)):

> A thread can wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied.

So threads in Java can wake up at any time. [A spurious wakeup is not very likely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050592/do-spurious-wakeups-in-java-actually-happen) but it can happen.