# Thread.sleep() hung

Tags: java

hi we are facing exactly same problem as described in but on a physical machine: [Thread.sleep() is hung?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749159/thread-sleep-is-hung)

machiry@pag02:~$ uname -a Linux pag02 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 16 16:22:28 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

machiry@pag02:~$ java -version java version "1.6.0_26" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, restart your machine. It's a [bug related to the leap second](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732) that occurred recently.

Comment: Thanks a ton Tomasz and Marko. you guys saved my time digging in to jstack dump.